# Microsoft Report Viewer (Web Forms) Version 13

Tags: asp.net, .net, reporting-services, webforms, gac

I have noticed that, after installing the April 2016 version of SSMS (located [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt238290.aspx)), an updated version of the `Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms` assembly (version 13) is installed in the GAC.

However, I cannot figure out how to add a reference to this assembly.  The only versions that show up in the "Add Reference" dialog are previous versions (versions 10 and 12 on my machine).

Is this assembly usable?  If so, how can I use it in a simple Web Forms project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft has released an early preview of the Report Viewer 13 controls on nuget. I have tested it out and found it to be working just as well as the viewer directly on the report server.

The only issue I have ran into is that hidden parameters now seem to leave a blank table cell in the toolbar rather than shifting the non-hidden parameters over.

SSMS or SSDT may have installed older versions of the controls which will need to be removed from the GAC in order for the report viewer control to render correctly (more info on this in the help page that comes with the preview).

> Preview report viewer on nuget: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportViewerControl.WebForms.Preview/

Answer (score 2):

I grabbed the `Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common`, `Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms`, `Microsoft.ReportViewer.ProcessingObjectModel`, and `Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebDesign` (new assembly) from the GAC in the August SSMS install and tried to use the control in a web application.

The assembly does not seem to be usable at this point. (version 13.0.1601.5)
The report does render, but the toolbar is messed up and none of the buttons appear to work.

Comment: do you have a public repo some where, with your test project?

Comment: Yes. Using the preview nuget package and updating to the latest SSDT release fixed it for me. `Install-Package Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportViewerControl.WebForms.Preview`